# How to create a mezzanine project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, mezzanine

Our company used to use Eclipse for all kinds of python development. We can create PyDev, GAE, or Django projects, but how do we create a Mezzanine project in Eclipse? There seems very little document about it.

Comment: You might have a look at this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mezzanine-users/_PVwlt0_dB0 . The answer by Miles Clark seems like a good start, if not a solution for your problem.

Comment: great. I will post the text as an answer, so it does not get lost if the link should die.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Miles Clark has answered this question over [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mezzanine-users/_PVwlt0_dB0). The releveant part is:

> Working with eclipse/pydev (not aptana, but it should be very similar), I normally create the project outside of eclipse and import it.  Roughly the steps are:
>
> - Create a virtualenv (I use virtualenvwrapper for this).  I include system site packages because I've found it easiest to install python-imaging and psycopg2 through the Ubuntu package manager rather than in each virtualenv.  I then install Mezzanine into the virtualenv, and create the project using the command line as described in the docs.
> - Once that's done, I'll create an interpreter entry in PyDev for the new virtualenv (Window > Preferences > PyDev > Interpreter - Python) and then import the project into eclipse.  Normally, I'll setup the new project in git and then import the git repo, but you can import without that if you'd like.  Choose pydev project, and make sure & choose the new interpreter that you created.
> - There's normally a little setup once the project's created in PyDev.  Make sure the project is marked as a Django project, and then see "Project Source Folders" in  Properties > PyDev - PYTHONPATH and the two settings in Properties > PyDev - Django.